# IPHONE Objective-C program using OPENSSL perform DES Encryption

Tags: iphone, objective-c, openssl, des

I have found an example about OPENSSL DES, when I applied this example into Objective-C program, the decrypted text was not equal to what I have input.

textField.text is the input textbox

Can anyone help me? Many thanks!!!

for e.g,

```
     when I input "test", the decrypted text ="test&\264"    
     when I input "Enter an Text here", the decrypted text ="Ente"    
     when I input "1234567890", the decrypted text ="1234h&\311"         
//ENCRYPTION
char* desen(char *clear, int size)    
{
    printf("Encrypted text\t  %s \n",clear);    
    char *encrypted;    
    char key[]="password";    
    encrypted=(char*)malloc(sizeof(clear));    
    static char*    Res;    
    int             n=0;    
    DES_cblock      Key2;    
    DES_key_schedule schedule;    

    Res = ( char * ) malloc( sizeof(clear) );    
    // Prepare the key for use with DES_cfb64_encrypt /    

    memcpy( Key2, key,8);    
    DES_set_odd_parity( &Key2 );    
    DES_set_key_checked( &Key2, &schedule );    


    // Encryption occurs here /    
    DES_cfb64_encrypt( ( unsigned char * ) clear, ( unsigned char * ) Res,    
      sizeof(clear), &schedule, &Key2, &n, DES_ENCRYPT );    

    memcpy(encrypted,Res, sizeof(clear));    
    printf("Key:%s\n",encrypted);    
    return encrypted;    
}     
//------------------------------------------------    
//DECRYPTION-------------------------------    
char* desde(char *clear, int size)    
{    
    char *decrypted;    
    char key[]="password";    
    decrypted=(char*)malloc(sizeof(clear));    

    static char* Res;    
    int n=0;    
    DES_cblock Key2;    
    DES_key_schedule schedule;    
    Res = ( char * ) malloc( sizeof(clear) );    
    // Prepare the key for use with DES_cfb64_encrypt /    
    memcpy( Key2, key,8);    
    DES_set_odd_parity( &Key2 );    
    DES_set_key_checked( &Key2, &schedule );    

    // Encryption occurs here /    
    DES_cfb64_encrypt( ( unsigned char * ) clear, ( unsigned char * ) Res,    
      sizeof(clear), &schedule, &Key2, &n, DES_DECRYPT );    

    memcpy(decrypted,Res, sizeof(clear));    

    printf("Key:%s\n",decrypted);    
    return decrypted;    
}    
    //------------------------------------------------    
    //----------Button------------------------------    
- (IBAction)calculateDES_ENCRYPT:(id)sender    
{    

    char key[]="password";    
    char *en;    
    char *de;    
    NSString *string =  textField.text;    
    const char *temp=[string fileSystemRepresentation];    
    int len=strlen(temp);    
    char clear[len+1];    
    //char clear[50];    
    strcpy(clear,temp);    

    en=desen( clear,len+1);    
    de= desde(en, len+1);    
}    
------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: DES should never, ever be used in the 21st century.

Answer (score 0):

This line

```
encrypted=(char*)malloc(sizeof(clear));
```

doesn't do what you think.  On a 32 bit system, sizeof(clear) will be 4 because it is the size of the pointer, not the length of the data pointed to.  So you are probably only encrypting/decrypting 4 bytes and you are printing out those 4 bytes plus some garbage.

Comment: thanks JeremyP, which function can replace "sizeof", as I am newbie in C Language.

Comment: If you want to encrypt the whole string including its terminating null character, you need `strlen(clear) + 1`. Note that the result is an array of bytes, **not a C null terminated string**.